# How to generate custom Nunit Report?

Tags: .net, nunit, selenium, nant

I am posting this query with lot of hope.

I have created a framework using Selenium RC with C#,Nunit and NANT.
and Implement Nunit2Report for converting XML report output from Nunit
to HTML format.

But the HTML report are not clear as we used to get using TestNG and
LoggingSelenium (Selenium Java Framework).

My Query:

> 1. Do we have any method to pass statement to Nunit report. Like in
>      winrunner we have tl_step  and in QTP we have reporter.reportevent to
>      alter test result.
> 2. Can we solve above issue using Listener.If yes please guide me on
>      this.
> 3. Do anybody have idea on how to generate Chart like report using
>      above framework scenario.

Thanks in advance.

Regards
Chidambaram

Answer (score 2):

NUnit does not have this built into it however you can possibly generate a listener.

http://nunit.org/index.php?p=eventListeners&r=2.5.7 describes how you can create your own listener. I have in the past just used my own logging file to see what is happening if you wanted. I have used NLog.

Since NUnit generates a XML document it shouldnt be too difficult to create a XSLT to transform the XML to the way you want it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I tried to implement Eventlistener after your comment and successfully created a Nunit Addin dll file.But how can we use this in our selenium C# test script.I am not good in C# but I can handle if i get a clue.Please guide me

Comment: Can you please provide me sample code for implement EventListener in Nunit with Selenium.